# Metrics do not get passed when using OpenTelemetry Agent used as INPUT at fluent-bit with http/protobuf protocol issue

Tags: fluent-bit

```
When Opentelemetry Agent used as INPUT, fluent-bit do not get/ pass Metrics from Otel Agent with http/protobuf protocol.
```

Below is the fluent-bit.conf I used, I get logs, traces but not the Metrices

fluent-bit.conf:

```
[SERVICE]
 Flush 1.000
  storage.path              /var/log/flb-storage/
  storage.sync              normal
  storage.checksum          off
  storage.max_chunks_up     200
  storage.backlog.mem_limit 5M

[INPUT]
  name              opentelemetry
  listen            0.0.0.0
  port              4322
  successful_response_code 200

[OUTPUT]
  name              stdout
  match             *
[OUTPUT]name              stdoutmatch             *
```

My console output

```
[0] v1_logs: [[xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx, {}], {"message"=>"Product Service: Fetched category: Electronics product name: FTR12311"}]
[2024/01/04 15:14:01] [ info] [output:opentelemetry:opentelemetry.1] 0.0.0.0:4318, HTTP status=200


|-------------------- RESOURCE SPAN --------------------|
  resource:
     - attributes:
            - host.arch: 'aarch64'
            - host.name: '<host-name>'
            - os.description: 'Mac OS X 14.1.2'
            - os.type: 'darwin'
            - process.command_args: [
                '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java',
                '-javaagent:/Users/<userid>/repos/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar',
                '-Dotel.service.name=java-demo-api',
                '-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp',
                '-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp',
                '-Dotel.logs.exporter=otlp',
                '-Dotel.exporter.otlp.protocol=http/protobuf',
                '-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://0.0.0.0:4322',
                '-jar',
                '/Users/<userid>/repos/java-demo-api/build/libs/java-demo-api-0.0.1.jar'
            ]
            - process.executable.path: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'
            - process.pid: 44546
            - process.runtime.description: 'Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 21+35-LTS-2513'
            - process.runtime.name: 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
            - process.runtime.version: '21+35-LTS-2513'
            - service.name: 'java-demo-api'
            - telemetry.auto.version: '1.32.0'
            - telemetry.sdk.language: 'java'
            - telemetry.sdk.name: 'opentelemetry'
            - telemetry.sdk.version: '1.32.0'
     - dropped_attributes_count: 0
  schema_url: https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.21.0
  [scope_span]
    instrumentation scope:
        - name                    : io.opentelemetry.tomcat-10.0
        - version                 : 1.32.0-alpha
        - dropped_attributes_count: 0
        - attributes:

    schema_url: 
    [spans]
         [span 'GET /products/{category}/{prdname}']
             - trace_id                : 3598b1419883634abf3acdece6759e39
             - span_id                 : 449ff602173a1772
             - parent_span_id          : undefined
             - kind                    : 2 (server)
             - start_time              : 1704361440906412000
             - end_time                : 1704361440921112458
             - dropped_attributes_count: 0
             - dropped_events_count    : 0
             - status:
                 - code        : 0
             - attributes: 
                 - net.host.name: 'localhost'
                 - user_agent.original: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
                 - http.target: '/products/Electronics/FTR12311'
                 - net.sock.peer.addr: '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1'
                 - thread.name: 'http-nio-8082-exec-4'
                 - net.host.port: 8082
                 - http.status_code: 200
                 - http.route: '/products/{category}/{prdname}'
                 - net.sock.host.addr: '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1'
                 - net.protocol.name: 'http'
                 - net.sock.peer.port: 49178
                 - thread.id: 45
                 - net.sock.host.port: 8082
                 - http.scheme: 'http'
                 - net.protocol.version: '1.1'
                 - http.method: 'GET'
             - events: none
             - [links]
  [scope_span]
    instrumentation scope:
        - name                    : io.opentelemetry.spring-webmvc-6.0
        - version                 : 1.32.0-alpha
        - dropped_attributes_count: 0
        - attributes:

    schema_url: 
    [spans]
         [span 'ProductController.getHelloMessage']
             - trace_id                : 3598b1419883634abf3acdece6759e39
             - span_id                 : cfc733891af5e382
             - parent_span_id          : 449ff602173a1772
             - kind                    : 1 (internal)
             - start_time              : 1704361440912994625
             - end_time                : 1704361440920345750
             - dropped_attributes_count: 0
             - dropped_events_count    : 0
             - status:
                 - code        : 0
             - attributes: 
                 - thread.id: 45
                 - thread.name: 'http-nio-8082-exec-4'
             - events: none
             - [links]
```

Here I am missing Metrics entries created at OpenTelemetry Java Agent and passed to fluent-bit. Not sure if Otel Agent fails to pass its Metrics to Fluent-bit collector OR Fluent-bit can not process the metrics from Otel Agent.

Original Log created at Otel Agent is...

Product Service: Fetched category: Electronics product name: FTR12311.